# Laravel Dusk not picking up APP_URL in .env.dusk.local file

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

Laravel dusk does not seem to use the APP_URL set in .env.dusk.local file.

This is my .env.dusk.local file:

```
APP_URL=http://local.project/
BASE_URL=http://local.project/
APP_ENV=testing
DB_CONNECTION=dusk
```

This is my login test:

```
<?php

 namespace Tests\Browser;

 use Tests\DuskTestCase;

     class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
     {

     /**
     * test_I_can_login_successfully
     *
     * @return void
     */
      public function test_I_can_login_successfully()
      {
             $this->browse(function ($browser) {
             $browser->visit('login')
                    ->keys('#email', 'test@test.co.uk')
                    ->keys('#password', 'test')
                    ->click('.btn-primary')
                    ->assertPathIs('dashboard')
                    ->assertSee('Marco');
                });
        }

   }
```

But when I run the test instead of going to http://local.project/login goes to http://localhost/public/local

Why is that?

Comment: What's the `APP_URL` value in your `.env` file?

Comment: It's same as in the .env.dusk.local.

Comment: What's the value of `dd(Browser::$baseUrl);`?

Comment: Could there be redirection occurring in the web application?